# Check number of items waiting in input buffer ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

If possible, how can I check the number of inputs waiting for me in the input buffer? That is, how many times can I reasonably assume that `getch` will return some sort of answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this indirectly by setting no timeout (e.g., using [`nodelay`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-nodelay)), and calling `getch` until an `ERR` is returned, and then (in reverse order) calling `ungetch` to restore the *fifo*.

That's not portable (X/Open Curses says only one `ungetch` might work), but ncurses has a *fifo* (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/cc47b5b8d3a66b3b4f4ff8383e7373b91ee41bbb/ncurses/curses.priv.h#L316)) which should allow up to 135 calls to getch/ungetch.

Doing this would interfere with functions (such as the mouse protocol, or function-key matchiing) that use multi-byte sequences of data, and would not necessarily work well with UTF-8.

Comment: That's what I came up with, but I was wondering if there was a more robust solution.

Comment: probably not: if there were a lot of demand for it (i.e., lots of unrelated developers), it might be a useful extension.